# Is the group algebra separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group. Is the group algebra $L^1(G)$ separable?
Would you please help me or introduce references that can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**No**, even if the group is compact, Abelian and separable. For instance, the [Cantor group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_cube) $\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable cardinal, is a good counter-example. This group is obviously compact and Abelian. It is also separable by the [Hewitt–Marczewski–Pondiczery theorem](http://planetmath.org/hewittmarczewskipondiczerytheorem). However $L_1(\{0,1\}^{\omega_1})$ is non-separable.

Indeed, if it were separable, the group C*-algebra $C^*_r(\{0,1\}^{\omega_1})$ would be separable as it contains $L_1(\{0,1\}^{\omega_1})$ as a dense subspace. This is not true because $$\widehat{\{0,1\}^{\omega_1} } = \bigoplus_{\alpha<\omega_1} \{0,1\}, $$
so you have uncountably pair-wise orthogonal non-zero projections in $C^*_r(\{0,1\}^{\omega_1})$.

Comment: And what is the criterion on the group? At least, the converse is true: if L1(G) is separable, then G also is?

Comment: Yulia, yes. $L_1(G)$ is separable if and only if $C_r(G)$ is separable (as the former is dense in the latter). $L_1(G)$ is separable if and only if $G$ is second-countable.

Comment: Dear Tomek, I am seeking without success a reference for this: $L^1(G)$ separable iff $G$ second countable. Can you please give me one?

Comment: Yulia, for compact groups this is a result of Grekas (Theorem 3.1 in http://sci-prew.inf.ua/v112/2/S0305004100071036.pdf; see also the corrigendum).

Comment: Oh my, I thought it was a 1960's result. For abelian groups, I have Hewitt/Ross 24.15. So you say it is unknown in general?.. Paper of Grekas is written in a vocabulary foreighn to me; do you mean Theorem 3.1 in it?

Comment: Well, I am not sure who proved that first and in what generality. Let's try to clarify the vocabulary: $w(G)$, the *weight* of $G$ is the minimal cardinality of a basis of open sets. So $G$ is second-countable if $w(G) \leqslant \aleph_0$. Now, the *Maharam type* of a measure $\mu$ is precisely the density character of $L_1(\mu)$. In other words, $L_1(\mu)$ is separable if and only if (by definition) $\mu$ has countable Maharam type. What Grekas did, he proved that $w(G)$ is precisely the Maharam type of the Haar measure of a compact group (this is much more than what you ask for).

Comment: I am not sure if one can extend Grekas result to general non-compact locally compact groups. (This should be doable in the case of $\sigma$-compact groups.) Haar measures on non-$\sigma$-compact groups should always have uncountable Maharam type (without knowing its exact value), so this is the way you can get your result. I haven't seen this written down anywhere, though. It's just part of the *common knowledge* that everybody knows, but nobody can say where does it come from.

Comment: Ok, indeed I don't need uncountable weights... but for countable, isn't it known however? We might move here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42310/when-is-l2x-separable

Comment: Maybe ask Dimitri Pavlov for a reference. I think it would be nice to extend Grekas' result to as general locally compact groups as possible.

Comment: Well, I can assume that G is $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Sorry, this proof was incorrect.

Comment: That's what I was going to write here :)

Comment: At least for totally disconnected groups it should follow from the compact case + van Dantzig's theorem. Please drop me a message, we can talk about that.

Answer (score 0):

No, because *any* discrete group is locally compact and admits a Haar measure that assigns the measure 1 to any element. $L^1$ on a non-countable set with such measure isn’t separable.

BTW I doubt that we necessarily have separability even for compact groups. Compactness is not a very strong condition to infer “nice” properties of function spaces. There are spaces that are compact and Hausdorff albeit very thick, in the sense there are damn much functions on them (although I am not sure it is the case for $L^1$).